# (Multidimensional) Standard Brownian Motion: Convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, brownian-motion

Relating to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/897245/convergence-to-standard-brownian-motion/897252?noredirect=1#comment1851909_897252), I have a further one, and hope, someone can help me.

I know that $$\left(X_j - X_{j-1}\right)_{j=1}^t \xrightarrow{d} \left(Y_j\right)_{j=1}^t.$$ 
Further, we know that $$\left(Y_j\right)_{j=1}^t=^d \left(W(y_j)-W(y_{j-1})\right)_{j=1}^t,$$ where $W$ is a Standard brownian Motion. 
Now, how do we get that 
$$\left(X_j\right)_{j=1}^t \xrightarrow{d} \left(W(y_j)\right)_{j=1}^t.$$

I think, it should be rather obvious, but I do not see it.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what X, Y and W are referring to, but all you need here is the general fact that if A converges to B in distribution, and B is equal to C in distribution, then A converges to C in distribution - this follows immediately from the definition of convergence in distribution.

Comment: yeah, I see your Point. But, this would only imply that 
$\left(X_j - X_{j-1}\right) \xrightarrow{d} \left(W(y_j)-W(y_{j-1})\right)$, and not the Statement above?

Comment: I mean, how can I say that if a sum of two summands convergences to a sum, that then each of the summands convergences to the summands..?

Comment: True, I misread your question. In this case, think about the case t=1. Then we have $X_1 - X_0 \rightarrow^d  W(y_1) - W(y_0)$. Without more information about what $X$, $W$ and $y_i$ are, I don't believe you can conclude that $X_1 \rightarrow^d  W(y_1)$. (As a counterexample, take $X_1 = X_0$ with N(0,1) distribution, say, and $W(y_1) = W(y_0)$ with N(0,2) distribution: both $X_1 - X_0$ and $W(y_1) - W(y_0)$ are 0 almost surely, so $X_1 - X_0 \rightarrow^d  W(y_1) - W(y_0)$. However it is not the case that $X_1 \rightarrow^d  W(y_1)$.

Comment: We know that $(Y_j)$ is a jointly normal Distribution with mean $0$, covariance always $0$, and some variance $>0$. 
Further, $y_j > y_{j-1}$ are fixed numbers. $W$ is a Standard brownian Motion. Is this enough, to Show this above? Maybe, that $y_j > y_{j-1}$ is the Point, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think the claim is true: take t=1, t_1=1 and t_0=0, and let X_1 = 0 a.s., X_0 ~ N(0,1), Y_1 ~ N(0,1). Then X_1 - X_0 is N(0,1), so is equal to Y_1 in distribution, which is equal to W(1) in distribution. However, X_1 is not equal to W(1) in distribution.

Comment: What would we Need then to prove that?
If you could take a look at it, I would really appreciate that:

http://arxiv.org/pdf/1012.3535v2.pdf

page 31, where we have 

$(Z(x_j)-Z(x_{j-1})) \xrightarrow{d} V_j$,
$V_j=^{d}( W( \frac{x_j^r}{r} )- W(\frac{x_{j-1}^r}{r}))$ and then, in the last sentence in the first section on this page, there is the conclusion.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have time for a detailed look, but it seems to me that x_0 is taken to be 0 (although I can't see this being explicitly stated), so we have that $(Z(x_l)-Z(x_{l-1}),\ldots,Z(x_2)-Z(x_1),Z(x_1)) \rightarrow^d (W(x_l)-W(x_{l-1}), \ldots, W_1)$. It might then be possible to make an argument that because $(Z(x_n),...,Z(x_1))$ is obtainable from $(Z(x_l)-Z(x_{l-1}),\ldots,Z(x_2)-Z(x_1),Z(x_1))$ via a linear transformation, this vector should convergence in distribution to the corresponding linear transformation of the W's.

Comment: And having thought aboue this a little more, I think that argument should work: in general, if $A_n \rightarrow^d B$, with $A_n,B$ taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous, then $f(A_n) \rightarrow^d f(B)$, since given a continuous bounded function $g: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$, we have $\int g(f(A_n)) dP \rightarrow \int g(f(B)) dP$, since the composite $gf$ is continuous and bounded, and $A \rightarrow^d B$ - this shows the definition of convergence in distribution is satisfied.

Comment: What do you even mean by $$(X_j-X_{j-1})_{j=1}^t \stackrel{d}{\to} (Y_j)_{j=1}^t;$$ convergence in distribution with respect to which index? (Usually, one considers a sequence of random variables $X^n$ and then $X^n \stackrel{d}{\to} X$ is well-defined. But here, you write something of the form $X \stackrel{d}{\to} Y$ where both $X$ and $Y$ are random variables.)

Comment: Thank you so so much for taking a look at it!! This is really nice!
Yes, you are right, $x_0$ is set to $0$. So the last component says $Z(x_1) \xrightarrow{d} W_1$. And with that, as we know that $Z(x_2)-Z(x_1) \xrightarrow{d} W_2 - W_1$, we can conclude that it must be that $Z(x_2) \xrightarrow{d} W_2$, and so on? Did I get your answer right?

Comment: @ saz: This is a multidimensional convergence, where each component convergences to the other component. 
thus $X_j - X_{j-1}$ converges to $Y_j$ 
That is, we have a sequence of random variables 
$X_j^{(i)}$, and the Limit of $X_j^{(i)}-X_{j-1}^{(i)}$ is $Y_j$. I hope, this is clearer now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your second answer. Thank you for your help, Mark!

Comment: You're welcome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It follows straight from the definition of convergence in distribution that

$$(X_j^n-X_{j-1}^n)_{j=1}^t \stackrel{d}{\to} (W(y_j)-W(y_{j-1}))_{j=1}^t.$$

Define a mapping $g: \mathbb{R}^t \to \mathbb{R}^t$ by

$$g(x) :=(x_1,x_1+x_2,\ldots,x_1+\ldots+x_t).$$

where $x := (x_1,\ldots,x_t)$. Then $g$ is continuous and

$$g((y_j-y_{j-1})_{j=1}^t) = (y_1,\ldots,y_t) \tag{1}$$

for any $y = (y_1,\ldots,y_t) \in \mathbb{R}^t$. Applying the continuous mapping theorem yields

$$g((X_j^n-X_{j-1}^n)_{j=1}^t) \stackrel{d}{\to} g((W(y_j)-W(y_{j-1}))_{j=1}^t).$$

Hence, by $(1)$, this is equivalent to

$$(X_j^n)_{j=1}^t \stackrel{d}{\to} (W(y_j))_{j=1}^t \qquad \text{as} \,\, n \to \infty.$$